Does the new M4 Pro chip support USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 standard?
Do the new M4 Pro Mac Mini and M4 Pro Macbook Pro, which now have Thunderbolt 5 ports, support the USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 standard?
USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 supports transfer speeds up to ~2,000 MB/s for SSDs, but the current Macs (up to M3 series) do no not support them, and default to ~1,000 MB/s.

Do you have a reference or experience why M3 Macs can’t encapsulate USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 at full speed? Does it negotiate a slower speed? Not connect at all? According to the official USB spec, this should be supported.

@bmike My understanding: 1) Gen2x2 is optional in USB4. 2) TB3 can't co-exisit with Gen2x2.  Since Apple seems committed to continuing support of TB3, I can't see Gen2x2 being available on any Mac. This is not authoritative enough for an answer.

I can’t find anything explaining whether Gen 2x2 needs to use 3x encapsulation either, so maybe Apple just “noped” this at the driver level since thunderbolt storage is so much more performant. Appreciate the details @Gilby

@bmike Yes the new 2000 MB/s non-thunderbolt SSDs (Like the Samsung T9 SSD, crucial X10 pro, etc) do connect, but work only limited to ~1000 MB/s on the M3 family chips, you can see it in the reviews.

Sounds good, these all ship now so hopefully someone will test for you or better the bendors of the drives you seek to use publicly commit to speeds on thunderbolt 4 and 5 as implemented by Apple. It sounds like you care less about the max speed on thunderbolt and really just need this specific USB 3 speed to be optimized?

I believe no gear exists to connect these devices in a way that works at full theoretical speed to Apple Silicon Mac hardware as of December 2024.
The specification indicates that even the M4 (non Pro) new mini has USB 4 which should encapsulate USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 at full speed.
The 13 inch M3 Air also has USB 4 / Thunderbolt 3 which could encapsulate the signal at full speed and you’re not alone in wanting this to work.

https://eclecticlight.co/2024/12/25/how-your-intel-mac-can-use-usb-3-2-gen-2x2-drives-at-full-speed/


your Intel Mac can now use that forbidden fruit, USB 3.2 Gen 2×2 at its full 20 Gb/s, as well as USB4 at a similar speed. Sadly, as I’ll explain later, if you have an Apple silicon Mac, you’ll still have to make do with 10 Gb/s or USB4.


The M3 SSDs support thunderbolt 4, and yes they support even 3000 MB/s Thunderbolt SSDs, like the SanDisk Professional 2TB PRO-G40™ SSD. But they do not support USB based SSDs like Samsung T9 SSD, crucial X10 pro rated at 2000MB/s , because they work on USB 3.2 Gen 2x2, and M3 Macbooks do not support USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 specifically, they fall back to 1000MB/s.  This is a known issue.

Let’s let someone that buys the gear answer now authoritatively

That person who has stepped up and purchased the gear and done the research is the esteemed Howard Oakley. See my  updated answer @Saharsh
